# I'm getting a YSOD error when trying to use ContentSearch in Azure PaaS

Tags: azure-search

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 Update 1 as PaaS on Azure.  I've added some new code that is giving me a strange error.

**Edit: Added more complete code**

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.CreateSearchContext(new SitecoreIndexableItem(Sitecore.Context.Item)))
{
    var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
        .Where(item => item.TemplateId == SitecoreItemIds.ISSUE_TEMPLATE &&
                    item.Path.StartsWith("/sitecore/content/Home/" + issueTypePath))
        .OrderByDescending(item => item["Date"])
        .FirstOrDefault();

        if (query != null)
            return query.GetItem();

        return null;
}
```

And I'm getting this YSOD error:

> Index (EMPTY) was not found
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException: Index
>   (EMPTY) was not found
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I'm using Azure Search as the search provider.  This code works on my local machine, but it's not hitting Azure Search.

I have not made any changes to files on Azure that would affect the search.

Comment: Can you reveal a little more code please? Can you show us how you're getting the index for the `context` var?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the search index as well?

Comment: @PeteNavarra I added additional code that should cover everything.

Trayek - I tried rebuilding the sitecore_master_index but I keep getting out of memory exceptions.  I may need to bump up my instance to rebuild the index.

Comment: FYI ... I was able to reindex after switching to an S3 instance.

Comment: @Kevin have you found solution to that issue ? it's happening for us as well, not consistently but randomly sometimes. I assumed that in some specific scenario when index is not initialized then it's happening and after some refresh it start working mostly after 2-3 refresh.

Answer (score 2):

The issue that I believe you are running into, is that no index is being defined. As part of the Search context, an index has to be identified.

Here's an example query highlighting the index selection:

```
var index  = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(“sitecore_web_index”);
using (var searchContext = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
var blogPosts = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
.Where(i => i.TemplateName == “Blog Post”);
}
```

Notice how I'm first defining which index I need to use, and then from the index, creating a search context.

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: An index is dynamically resolved from the `SitecoreIndexableItem` and `CreateSearchContext()` calls GetIndex so the correct context should be returned. The code the OP posted is correct and should work. http://getfishtank.ca/en/blog/dynamically-resolving-your-content-search-index

Comment: The clue i was basing off of is the error. It seems that it can't resolve the index. I agree that it should work, but what I'm thinking is that because it can't resolve the index, one has to be specified.

Comment: Agree that specifying the index may solve the issue, but it does not resolve the underlying cause.

Comment: Agreed. I'll do some testing my Azure instance to see if I can replicate issue. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I updated my code according to your suggestion and it seems to have resolved that particular error, but now I'm not getting any results.  This does not happen locally and I cannot attach a remote debugging session.

Comment: You can also search a Bucket item this way: var index = new SitecoreIndexableItem(bucketItem);

Comment: I don't know why it's not getting the correct context, but that's something I can overcome.  But I did a bit of diagnostics in Azure Search.

`search=template_1:(3bccaa2624a9456bae9576e75586a9b8)%20AND%20fullpath_1:(/%5C/sitecore%5C/content%5C/Home%5C/Daily.*/)&queryType=full&$orderby=date%20desc&$count=true`

It doesn't like the path portion of the request. If I remove the %5Cs it works within Search Explorer. (e.g. (/sitecore/content/Home/Daily.*))

Comment: Was there a resolution to this problem. My code also uses the same approach to get the Index on Sitecore 8.2u5 , but I see this error in my prod logs a few times daily. Could it be due to searchstax un-availability or any other error . I am on Azure PAAS